# Tumblr Theme - Different Style for each post type

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm creating a Tumblr theme, and I've run into a problem, of sorts. I like all of my posts to be these big circles with a different coloured border per post type. I don't know how to do this. Right now I can put ALL post to have a border and be rounded to the size I want, but, for example, I'd like text posts to have a red border, and photo posts to have an orange border. I've tried putting a div around text posts in the coding and adding the border that way, but it creates a secondary border (around the one I already set for ALL posts) and doesn't include the post's info (i.e the date and tags and such).

Does anyone know how to add different borders around each post type that includes the WHOLE post?

Here's the theme live for reference https://rainbowdotsinspiredthemetestblog.tumblr.com/

Heres the coding I have so far (my posts are labeled as stuff)

```
#stuff {
                float:left;
                width:400px;
                height:400px;
                margin-top:25px;
                margin-left:25px;
                text-align:justify;
                font-size:11px;
                line-height:90%;
                padding:5px;
                letter-spacing:0px;
                border:5px #24E4D8 solid;
                border-radius:200px;
                overflow:scroll;
                overflow-x:hidden;
                }
<!--TEXT POSTS-->
<div class="testingtext">
{block:Text}{block:Title}<h3>{Title}</h3>{/block:Title}{Body}{/block:Text}</div>
```

This is what I tired and does NOT work

```
#stuff .testingtext{
        border:5px red solid;
    }
#stuff>.testingtext{
            border:5px red solid;
        }
#stuff:.testingtext{
            border:5px red solid;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should be using a *class* `stuff` and not and ID. An ID should be unique and not repeated anywhere on a page.

Secondly, you can solve your problem with something like this:

```
<div class="stuff {PostType}-post">
    [post stuff]
</div>
```

`{PostType}` is the name of the current post type.

Then your CSS would just be like:

```
.text-post { border-color: red; }
.photo-post { border-color: orange; }
.chat-post { border-color: yellow; }
```

etc.

Comment: This could be simplified with `<div class="{PostType}-post"></div>`. Source: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts

Comment: @mikedidthis thanks! i'll edit my answer now, have always skimmed over that variable but it's gonna help me in themes of my own haha

Answer (score 1):

You can create classes for each color in your CSS.

```
.red { border: 5px red solid }
.orange { border: 5px orange solid }
/* and so on */
```

Then assign the classes to the post types in your HTML.

```
{block:Text}
<div class="post red">
    {block:Title}<h3>{Title}</h3>{/block:Title}
    {Body}
</div>
{/block:Text}

{block:Photo}
<div class="post orange">
    {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" border="0" alt="{PhotoAlt}">{LinkCloseTag}
    {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
</div>
{/block:Photo}
```

and so on, for all post types. Hope this helps!

Comment: This won't work, as in the question it says that they tried a `div` around the whole text block, but it doesn't include the common code (ie the dates and tags).